# How do I move a layer 1px Down and 1px Right?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have created a layer and I need to move it exactly 1 pixel right and 1 pixel down. How do I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 9):

- Make sure the layer you want to move is active in the Layers palette
- Make sure you're viewing at 100% or greater zoom
- Select the Move tool
- Click right cursor key, then down cursor key to move 1px in each direction; hold Shift to increase this to 10px

Comment: Well, that was helpfull ! What do I do if I want to move the layer by some certain required amount of pixels? Like say, to move it by 20 pixels right and 30 pixels down!

Comment: Holding Shift increases the amount the cursor keys move the object to 10px. Or you could drag the layer while watching the cursor XY values in the Info palette.

Comment: Another way that I sometimes use if things are getting more complicated is to create a new image with a off color background say bright pink or bright green. Make it the width I need to move things by and then just drop it in, snap to object, then move object to snap to other side. I especially use this if I'm trying to get something divided by 3rds.

Comment: Yeah, do make sure you're at 100% zoom. Photoshop's nudge increments are based on MONITOR PIXELS at increments < 100%, so you might actually be nudging it 2px at a time if you're at, say, 50% zoom.

Answer (score 4):

Select the layer you want to move and go to Free Transform ( Ctrl+T on PC, Cmd+T on Mac )
Then right below the Menu bar, you'll see the Free Transform options come up.

[image: Triangle unchecked]

Click the triangle button in between X and Y co-ordinates.

[image: Triangle checked]
Now you can move your layer/selection at the pixel level.
Go ahead and play around with it.

(The triangle allows you to move the layer with reference to the old co-ordinates as opposed to absolute ones.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with the cursor when your view is on 100%. Some people keep a second view of the document open specifically for this purpose. So that they can stay in zoomed view in one window and move things in another.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Check to make sure the layer you want to move is selected.

**2.** Hit your right arrow key, and then your down arrow key.

Comment: (-1) I see no point in this answer since it doesn't give any more info than what has already been given by @e100's answer. Not to discourage answering, but I just see no point in this, since it doesn't bring anything new to the table.. :/